# Flutter http Response body is empty

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to retrieve data from this API " **https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/** " but every time I make an **http.get()** request the response's body is empty can anyone please try my code and see if the problem is with flutter or with me

I've already had this issue a while ago where this code wasn't working for me but worked fine when someone else tried it and I the problem was fixed after I did a " **Flutter upgrade** " but the problem occurred again and I can't understand where is the problem and it's making me really anxious.

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<String> getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http
        .get(
      "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/",
    )
        .then((value) {
      print(value.body.toString());
      return value;
    });
    var data = response.body;
    print(data); //Shows nothing
    print(data.isEmpty); // "TRUE"
    print(data.length); // "0"
    return response.body;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          getData();
        },
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Hello World"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use either `async await` or `then`.
Change your code to this.

```
Future<String> getData() async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(
    "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/",
  );
  return response.body;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry but the problem wasn't solved I tried your code and the body is still empty !

Comment: I tried and got the same result. The issue is with the API. I sent the request in Postman without a trailing slash in the URL (i.e., [https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static](https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static)) and got an empty body. Guess the issue is related with the way in which dart escapes URL.

Comment: I really couldn't understand where the problem is I asked a friend to try the code on his pc he tried it on an Iphone simulator and it worked fine the problem is is not in the API but I don't know where it is.